# Encrypt partition from the command line with PGP Desktop

Tags: command-line, partitioning, encryption, pgp-desktop

How do you encrypt a partition, instead of a full disk, with PGP Desktop, from the command line? To encrypt a whole disk there seems to be a --disk argument, but I can't find how to do it for partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is something along these lines.

> pgpwde --encrypt --passphrase "your password goes here" --disk "#" --partition "#"

[This article](https://pgp.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/887) may give you more insight, it talks about the decrypt.

Comment: It seems that's the correct syntax. Nevertheless I'm getting Error code -11975: "feature not available", do you know if that's a licensing issue or something else?

Comment: Yes it is a licensing issue. http://forum.pgp.com/t5/PGP-Whole-Disk-Encryption-for/Encrypt-disk-using-PGPWDE/m-p/24702